# Phantom messages in Exchange Calendar folder

Tags: exchange-server, imap

I'm developing an IMAP client, and testing it against a Microsoft Exchange server.  When I select the `Calendar` mailbox, `UID SEARCH` suggests that there are messages in the mailbox, but `UID FETCH` cannot fetch them:

```
S: * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready.
...
C: 38 SELECT "Calendar"
S: * 13 EXISTS
S: * 0 RECENT
S: * FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
S: * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)] Permanent flags
S: * OK [UIDVALIDITY 37122] UIDVALIDITY value
S: * OK [UIDNEXT 190] The next unique identifier value
S: 38 OK [READ-WRITE] SELECT completed.
C: 39 UID SEARCH OR UNSEEN FLAGGED
C: 40 UID SEARCH SEEN UNFLAGGED SINCE 19-Oct-2014
S: * SEARCH
S: 39 OK SEARCH completed.
S: * SEARCH 90 183
S: 40 OK SEARCH completed.
C: 41 UID FETCH 90,183 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[])
S: 41 OK FETCH completed.
```

I presume that `Calendar` is some kind of virtual mailbox, but this behaviour doesn't make sense to me — why would the server return the message uids in `UID SEARCH` if it's not possible to `FETCH` them? Is there any way to fetch these messages, or somehow manipulate them using IMAP?

---

*Update*: After being upgraded to 2010 SP3, it seems like the Exchange server had a change of heart.  Now it at least returns something in response to the `FETCH` command:

```
C: 120 UID FETCH 773,948 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE FLAGS BODY.PEEK[])
S: * 16 FETCH (ENVELOPE (NIL "Retrieval using the IMAP4 protocol failed for the following message: 773" (("Microsoft Exchange Server 2010" NIL NIL ".MISSING-HOST-NAME.")) NIL NIL (("██████████" NIL "██████████" "██████████")) NIL NIL NIL NIL) INTERNALDATE "05-Mar-2015 17:22:02 +0000" FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[] {783}
S: <783 bytes omitted>
S:  UID 773)
S: * 17 FETCH (ENVELOPE (NIL "Retrieval using the IMAP4 protocol failed for the following message: 948" (("Microsoft Exchange Server 2010" NIL NIL ".MISSING-HOST-NAME.")) NIL NIL (("██████████" NIL "██████████" "██████████")) NIL NIL NIL NIL) INTERNALDATE "11-Mar-2015 17:56:04 +0000" FLAGS (\Seen) BODY[] {747}
S: <747 bytes omitted>
S:  UID 948)
S: 120 OK FETCH completed.
```

The messages look like this:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
From: Microsoft Exchange Server 2010
To: ███████████ <████████@██████████.com>
Subject: Retrieval using the IMAP4 protocol failed for the following
 message: 773
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

The server couldn't retrieve the following message:

Subject: "████ █████ ███████ ██ ████ ███ █████ ███████.. ███ ███ ██████ ███=
██!"
From: "███████████  ██████████" ("/O=3D████████/OU=3D████████ █████████████=
█ █████ (███████████████)/CN=3D██████████/CN=3D███████████  █████████████")
Sent date: 3/5/2015 5:22:02 PM

The message hasn't been deleted. You might be able to view it using either =
Outlook or Outlook Web App. You can also contact the sender to find out wha=
t the message says.=
```

Comment: The server says 13 EXISTS, so FETCH 1:13 (ENVELOPE...) should return something. But so should UID FETCH 90. I'm really just suggesting a way to perhaps tiptoe around the server bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a server bug. It is not a secret that Exchange "implaments IMAP" in order to be able to tick a required checkbox when evaluating tenders. You will see other bugs in there as well.

It might be interesting to get a list of all UIDs which that mailbox allegedly contains, and to try fetching them one-by-one to see if at least some of them return some usable value. However, considering that this is a mailbox called "Calendar", chances are that it's just some random Exchange export of data which only make sense via MAPI. Random googling results in https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998606%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx which suggests that Exchange can be configured to offer these calendar data in various formats. Maybe your server is "misconfigured".

TL;DR: it's Exchange. Don't waste time on it.